# How to catch error when fetching json and updating it with fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I want this `setMessage` to not display when I have  `PUT ERROR 404 not found` in `updateTemplate` function. I tried it with `catch(err)` but I didn't succeed.

Full code snippet:

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [templates, setTemplates] = useState([]);
  const [template, setTemplate] = useState({ templateName: "", tags: [] });
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    getTemplates();
  }, []);

  async function getTemplates() {
    await fetch("http://localhost:8080/templates").then((result) => {
      result.json().then((resp) => {
        setTemplates(resp);
      });
    });
  }

  function selecTemplate(templateName) {
    let item = templates.find((t) => t.templateName === templateName);
    setTemplate(item);
    setMessage("");
  }

  async function updateTemplate() {
    let item = {
      id: template.id,
      templateName: template.templateName,
      tags: template.tags,
    };
    console.warn("item", item);
    await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/templates/${template.id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
    }).then((result) => {
      result.json().then((resp) => {
        console.warn(resp);
        getTemplates();
        setMessage("Update succesful");
      });
    });
  }

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target);
    if (event.target.name === "name") {
      setTemplate({ ...template, name: event.target.value });
    } else {
      var tags = template.tags;
      switch (event.target.name) {
        case "tag0":
          tags[0] = event.target.value;
          break;
        case "tag1":
          tags[1] = event.target.value;
          break;
        case "tag2":
          tags[2] = event.target.value;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      setTemplate({ ...template, tags: tags });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="table-responsive">
          <table className="table table-dark" border="1">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td className="bg-info">Name</td>
                <td className="bg-info">Select template</td>
              </tr>

              {templates.map((item, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{item.templateName}</td>

                  <td>
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-danger"
                      onClick={() => selecTemplate(item.templateName)}
                    >
                      Select
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div className="inputs">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={template.templateName}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />{" "}
          <br />
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="tag0"
            value={template.tags[0]}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />{" "}
          <br />
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="tag1"
            value={template.tags[1]}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />{" "}
          <br />
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="tag2"
            value={template.tags[2]}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />{" "}
          <br />
          <br />
          <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={updateTemplate}>
            Update Template
          </button>
          <p style={{ color: "green", marginTop: "10px" }}>{message}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Below is the image of the error I am getting, I want to display "Update failed" instead "Update successful" when I get it:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch()` throws an error on its own only when there is a network error, like the server not being able to respond. Here is [note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful) from mdn:

> A `fetch()` promise will reject with a `TypeError` when a network error is encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server-side, although this usually means permission issues or similar — a 404 does not constitute a network error, for example. An accurate check for a successful `fetch()` would include checking that the promise resolved, then checking that the `Response.ok` property has a value of true.

For other types of errors like a 404 in your case, you could use a check and throw an error yourself and then catch it, like so:

```
async function updateTemplate() {
  let item = {
    id: template.id,
    templateName: template.templateName,
    tags: template.tags,
  };
  console.warn("item", item);
  await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/templates/${template.id}`, {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(item),
  })
    .then((result) => {
      if (!result.ok) throw Error("Update failed"); // line I added
      return result.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.warn(data);
      getTemplates();
      setMessage("Update succesful");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      setMessage("Update failed");
    });
}
```